# How to close a custom read/write stream in rust

Tags: rust, stream, pipe, channel

Here is a readable and writable stream that I have implemented. I have used `try_clone` clones multiple times in multiple threads. How can I safely close this `VirtualStream` so that I can respond to `HTTP` requests normally. If there were a better way to implement VirtualStream, it would be even better. Thanks for your attention.

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, RecvError, Sender};

pub struct VirtualStream {
    tx1: Sender<Vec<u8>>,
    rp1: Arc<Receiver<Vec<u8>>>,
    tx2: Sender<Vec<u8>>,
    rp2: Arc<Receiver<Vec<u8>>>,
}

unsafe impl Sync for VirtualStream {}

unsafe impl Send for VirtualStream {}

impl VirtualStream {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (tx1, rp1): (Sender<Vec<u8>>, Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = channel();
        let (tx2, rp2): (Sender<Vec<u8>>, Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = channel();

        VirtualStream {
            rp1: Arc::new(rp1),
            tx1,
            rp2: Arc::new(rp2),
            tx2,
        }
    }

    pub fn produce(&self, buf: &[u8]) {
        // provide data
        let _ = self.tx1.send(buf.to_vec());
    }

    pub fn accept(&self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, RecvError> {
        // consume  data
        self.rp2.recv().map_err(|e| e.into())
    }
    pub fn shutdown(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        // close stream
        println!("shuwdown....");
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn try_clone(&self) -> Option<Self> {
        let tx1 = self.tx1.clone();
        let tx2 = self.tx2.clone();
        let rp1 = self.rp1.clone();
        let rp2 = self.rp2.clone();
        let cloned = VirtualStream { rp1, tx1, rp2, tx2 };
        Some(cloned)
    }
}

impl Read for VirtualStream {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        match self.rp1.recv() {
            Ok(data) => {
                let len = data.len().min(buf.len());
                buf[0..len].copy_from_slice(&data[0..len]);
                println!("read ok");
                Ok(len)
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("read error");
                Err(io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock.into())
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Write for VirtualStream {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let writer = self.tx2.borrow_mut();
        writer.send(buf.to_vec()).unwrap();
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        // no cache
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4000").unwrap();
    println!("Forward 127.0.0.1:4000 to 127.0.0.1:8000");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        if let Ok(mut client) = stream {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut client2 = client.try_clone().unwrap();
                let mut client3 = client.try_clone().unwrap();
                let mut v_stream0 = VirtualStream::new();
                // let virtual_stream1 = v_stream0.try_clone().unwrap();
                let mut virtual_stream2 = v_stream0.try_clone().unwrap();
                let mut virtual_stream3 = v_stream0.try_clone().unwrap();

                thread::spawn(move || loop {
                    println!("listen v_stream0 data");
                    match v_stream0.accept() {
                        Ok(data) => {
                            let string_result = std::str::from_utf8(&data).unwrap();
                            println!("http request packet:{:?}", string_result);
                            v_stream0.produce("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nhello world123".as_bytes());
                            v_stream0.shutdown().expect("Failed to shutdown");
                            println!("after shutdown called");
                        }
                        Err(err) => {
                            // closed stream, then shutdown client
                            print!("close detect...{:?}", err);
                            client
                                .shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Write)
                                .expect("falied close stream");
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    let _ = io::copy(&mut virtual_stream2, &mut client2);
                    println!("copy virtual stream to client complete or error...1");
                });
                let _ = io::copy(&mut client3, &mut virtual_stream3);
                println!("copy client to virtual stream complete or error...2");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

testing with `telnet`:

```bash
☁  ~  telnet 127.0.0.1 4000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

hello world123
```

testing with `curl`:

```bash
☁  examples [master] ⚡  curl -vs http://127.0.0.1:4000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 4000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:4000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
```

Comment: Your `unsafe impl` blocks for both `Send` and `Sync` are unsound. Generally you should not implement these traits manually unless you are absolutely certain that it is safe to do so. Neither `Sender` nor `Receiver` are `Sync`, and your `unsafe impl`s allow unsynchronized access to both of them.

Comment: @cdhowie Can you help me improve the code? What should I do

Comment: I will draft an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, your `unsafe impl` blocks for both `Send` and `Sync` are unsound. Neither `Sender` nor `Receiver` are `Sync`, and your `unsafe impl`s allow unsynchronized access to both of them.

Generally you should not implement these traits manually unless you are absolutely certain that it is safe to do so.  **If you aren't sure what "soundness" means then you should not use the `unsafe` keyword.**

It looks like you're just trying to create a `Read` and `Write` pair where what is written to the `Write` end is produced from the `Read` end.  You can implement this directly on top of `Sender` and `Receiver`:

```
use std::{
    io::{Read, Write},
    sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender}, time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ChannelWrite(Sender<Vec<u8>>);

impl Write for ChannelWrite {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.0
            .send(buf.into())
            .map_err(|e| std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::BrokenPipe, e))?;

        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ChannelRead {
    rx: Receiver<Vec<u8>>,
    current: Vec<u8>,
    current_pos: usize,
}

impl Read for ChannelRead {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        if buf.len() == 0 {
            return Ok(0);
        }

        loop {
            let remaining = self.current.len() - self.current_pos;
            if remaining > 0 {
                let to_fill = std::cmp::min(remaining, buf.len());
                buf[..to_fill]
                    .copy_from_slice(&self.current[self.current_pos..(self.current_pos + to_fill)]);
                self.current_pos += to_fill;
                return Ok(to_fill);
            }

            match self.rx.recv() {
                Ok(b) => {
                    self.current = b;
                    self.current_pos = 0;
                }
                Err(_) => return Ok(0),
            };
        }
    }
}

pub fn channel_pipe() -> (ChannelWrite, ChannelRead) {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    (
        ChannelWrite(tx),
        ChannelRead {
            rx,
            current: vec![],
            current_pos: 0,
        },
    )
}
```

It's very rare that you actually need both read and write capabilities at once.  Usually you have a unidirectional stream of bytes, which is what is implemented here.

Note that `ChannelWrite` derives `Clone` so you can simply clone the writer and give them to multiple threads.

`ChannelRead` cannot be cloned because `Receiver` cannot.

To use this, you would do something like `let (mut write, mut read) = channel_pipe();` and distribute the writer(s) around where needed, then you can read from the `read` side.

Note that:

- Send errors are converted to an `std::io::Error` with the kind `BrokenPipe`.  You will get this error if you try to write after the reader is dropped.
- Receive errors can only happen when all senders are dropped, which simply indicates that there is no more data to be read, so reading will return `Ok(0)` to signal this.  The reader will therefore never produce any I/O errors whatsoever.

So, the way you "close" this kind of "virtual stream" is simply to drop all of the writers (implicitly by having them go out of scope, or explicitly with [`drop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html)).  Once you do so, the reader will signal end-of-stream by returning `Ok(0)` (once all queued/buffered data has been read, of course).

Here is a simple example where the reader is given to a thread:

```
fn main() {
    let (mut write, mut read) = channel_pipe();

    let th = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut buf = [0; 1024];
        loop {
            match read.read(&mut buf).unwrap() {
                0 => break,
                v => println!("read: {:?}", from_utf8(&buf[..v]).unwrap()),
            };
        }
    });

    for i in 0..10 {
        write.write_all(format!("hello, {i}").as_bytes()).unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
    }

    drop(write);

    th.join().unwrap();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1685741bee60c72a601cacce506817d))

Comment: thanks!  [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdf425c8da64ebe6f9c31b51f36f8736),  How can it be closed normally in this situation?  Additionally, can we implement a stream that is readable and writable like TcpStream?

Comment: @Hai.Xu If a stream is both readable and writable, where do the writes go and where do the reads come from? Are you trying to implement unidirectional or bidirectional communication?

Comment: @Hai.Xu In the playground you have `let mut writeer_1 = writeer.clone();` but you only use `writeer_1` and you never use `writeer`. You don't need to clone at all, just use `writeer`.

Comment: hi! I am attempting to implement a tunnel where data can be read and written from the tunnel, and then streamed to the sender and receiver ends.

Comment: @Hai.Xu That doesn't really answer my question. You can't "move through streams to the sending end" by definition; a sending end doesn't receive data. This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you back up and describe the higher-level problem you are trying to solve, without talking about streams?

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with my description. I simply want to implement something resembling `TcpStream`, which can be utilized by `io::copy`.

Comment: @Hai.Xu So you want bidirectional in-process communication?

Comment: If I understood correctly, it should be just as you said. I want to implement a bidirectional `stream`, often referred to as a duplex stream in other languages, which allows simultaneous reading and writing. In my target program, it will be simulated on a single `TCP` connection, similar to the concept of `stream`  in `HTTP/2`. Same as `TcpStream` in rust.  I also raised a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76602439/how-to-implement-a-custom-stream-in-rust-such-as-tcpstream), but it seems like no one answered me.

Comment: @Hai.Xu In that case you just need two of these channel-based streams. In other words, you do `let (write1, read1) = channel_pipe(); let (write2, read2) = channel_pipe();`. Then you give `(read1, write2)` to one side and `(read2, write1)` to the other side. Now both sides have a way to send the other data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your suggestion.