# How to implement a custom stream in rust, such as TcpStream

Tags: rust, stream, pipe, duplex

How to implement a custom stream in rust, such as `TcpStream`, but not TcpStream.
For example, the encrypted stream called `MyStream` below It can be used by pipelines

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;


fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4000").unwrap();
    println!("Forward 127.0.0.1:4000 to 127.0.0.1:8000");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        if let Ok(client) = stream {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                if let Ok(encrypt_socket) = MyTcpStream::new("127.0.0.1:8000") {
                    println!("connect 127.0.0.1:8000 success");
                    let encrypt_socket2 = encrypt_socket.try_clone().unwrap();
                    let client2 = client.try_clone().unwrap();
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        let _ = io::copy(&mut encrypt_socket2, &mut client2);
                    });
                    let _ = io::copy(&mut client, &mut encrypt_socket);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is to implement the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) and/or [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html) traits, isn't it?

Comment: @rodrigo Yes! Also, I would like to use it in a pipeline manner. For example, in io::copy. Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: `io::copy()` just requires that the first argument implements `Read` and the second one implements `Write`. Just try implementing those and see if it is enough for you.

Comment: @rodrigo Perhaps you are right, but it's not what I'm looking for.